# Export Array of entries in modifyEntryTableAttributes

Tags: entries, plugins

I am trying to return an array of selected entries in the list view, but so far I can only get `first()` and `last()` to export the names, since it's only grabbing one entry. I would like to get a comma separated list of entries tied the that specific entry.

I have tried using `find()` and `find()->title` but it gives me an error.

Here's what I have right now.

```
    public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute){
     if ($attribute == 'sponsorEntries'){
      return '<span>'.$entry->sponsorEntries->first().'</span>';
     }
    }
```

and then I call it:

```
        // Artists
     public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source){
      if ($source == 'section:9'){
        $attributes['sponsorEntries'] = Craft::t('Sponsor');
      }
     }
```

but I would like to get return all the entries, not just the first() one like the screenshot below illustrates.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the `find` method rather than `first` and `last`, in order to pull all the entries.

Then, you'll have to *loop through the entries*, appending their titles to a variable which will be used for the attribute's HTML value in the list view.

Here, I'm pushing the entry titles to an array called `$tempArray`. After looping, the array is joined and returned as a comma separated list:

```
public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute == 'sponsorEntries')
    {
        if ($sponsorEntries = @$entry->$attribute->find())
        {
            $tempArray = [];
            foreach ($sponsorEntries as $sponsorEntry)
            {
                $tempArray[] = $sponsorEntry->title;
            }
            // Will return "Awesome Entry, Another Awesome Entry"
            return implode(', ', $tempArray);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to, you can also make the entry titles in the list view clickable – i.e., to make it easy for your content editor to edit those entries – by wrapping the titles in anchor tags and pulling the entries' `cpEditUrl` property:

```
if ($sponsorEntries = @$entry->$attribute->find())
{
    $tempArray = [];
    foreach ($sponsorEntries as $sponsorEntry)
    {
        $tempArray[] = '<a href="' . $sponsorEntry->cpEditUrl . '">' . $sponsorEntry->title . '</a>';
    }
    return implode(', ', $tempArray);
 }
```

...or if you prefer, you can make the links point to the entries on the frontend, by using `$sponsorEntry->url` instead:

```
$tempArray[] = '<a href="' . $sponsorEntry->url . '" target="_blank">' . $sponsorEntry->title . '</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when adding this to getEntryTableAttributeHtml and reloading the entries, I get a blank list (nothing renders), do I have to update `modifyEntryTableAttributes` too? Right now I just have `$attributes['sponsorEntries'] = Craft::t('Sponsor(s)');`

Comment: Nope, looks good :)

Comment: hm, I can't seem to get it working. The list page goes blank when adding either of the code samples.

Comment: I tested it and the code runs fine on my end. If the page goes blank its a PHP error; turn on dev mode and you'll likely see an error message. Also check logs under /craft/storage/runtime/logs

Comment: Well actually I just spotted a typo in my example – had ```$element``` in place of ```$entry``` in a couple of spots. Edited the answer; should be correct now. Sorry about that – test again and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Sorry about this, but nope, it's now giving me a `An unknown error occurred.` but if I remove it and revert back into my old code `if ($attribute == 'sponsorEntries'){ $cat = $entry->sponsorEntries->first(); return '<span>'.$cat.'</span>';}` it starts working again.

Comment: Did you check your logs? Might be a more helpful error message in there.

Comment: Ya when I switch `@$element` to `@$entry` it gives me `An unknown error occurred.` I'm in dev mode and I'm not getting any error logs

Comment: Okay, what you can do, is to fire up Dev Tools in your browser of choice and refresh the page. When the AJAX call to ```getElements``` fails, you should see it in the Network pane. Click it, and you might see the original CException error and stack trace ([its going to look something like this](http://cly.mmikkel.no/image/0Y140l141G1J)).

Comment: Hey, yep got this, http://grab.by/KPwq     http://grab.by/KPwK

Comment: @knynkwl can you share the full stack trace of the error past `#0` and `#1`?

Comment: @knynkwl Right, that doesn't appear to be an error within the ```getEntryTableAttributeHtml``` code, per se – looks like a separate issue. It's weird that it doesn't occur when you use ```first``` and ```last``` over ```find``` though... its possibly isolated to one or several entries inbetween the first and last one?

Comment: @BradBell there is two links in my comment above with the full stack error. but here it is again.  http://grab.by/KPwq thanks

Comment: @mmikkel Is it possible that we have to test if there is at least one entry available before running your code? Some entries are not assigned a Sponsor Entry.

Comment: Not really, thats what the @ is there for. It suppresses errors if the attribute isn't found on the entry. And if it's there, but empty, the implode statement will just return an empty string.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. damn haha

Comment: Coming back to this, It seemed to work. Must have been a cache issue or something. Thanks again @mmikkel!